# Style not being applied in IE8 for specific page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Hi I am having a problem with a site I made [Ace IT Solutions](http://www.aceitsolutions.co.uk/). Basically on the IT Support page none of the positioning style is loading however on every other page the style loads. I have been trying to figure this out for ages now and cannot solve it. Oh and any coding and styling tips would be much appreciated I am only an apprentice. :) Please help.

Comment: Show us some code on here please! The site you've linked to may change in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josh,

Then I think it's your html code causing problems.

If I look at source on IE8, I get 2 html tags:

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

What I would do is using one html tag only, and using your conditional IE logic to add only css classes.

If you do not see what I mean, can give you a code example.

My feeling is something wrong happen on IE prior to 9, and browser is lost.

Comment: Yes it was that first <html> that was causing it to break. I was using modx and it was the only template with <html> in it while the others use my {{head}} chunck. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

that's because  you put the styling into media query, which are not handled by IE8. 
for example, change:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1240px) {
  .container .five.columns {
  width: 335px;
  }
}
```

to

```
.container .five.columns {
  width: 335px;
}
```

do this for all relevant elements

Comment: Instead of updating each media queries entry in css, I would suggest to use css3-mediaqueries-js script to emulate media queries.

you will find it at https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: @franchez that is the thing I am using css3-mediaqueries-js already.